# how to get each country name once from country column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to fetch each country's name once from the country column.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/resbaz/r-novice-gapminder-files/master/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv
I wrote this code, but each country's name appears more than one time. I need to know how many countries name are there..how will I do that?

```
df1=pd.read_csv('FiveYearData.csv')
print(df1)

df2 = df1['country']
print(df2)
```

Comment: check second answer.

Comment: df1['country'].unique() will give you the unique names, thanks!